# Parallel computation with cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, parallel-processing, cell

`A`,`B`,`C`: cell arrays of size 100 x 1.
Each cell of `A` is a matrix. All have same size.
`B` and `C` contain vectors.

I need to create a cell array `D` of size 100 x 1. Serial code will look something like:

```
for i=1:100
    D{i}=my_func(A{i},B{i},C{i});
end
```

where `my_func` is a function that takes input of a matrix and vectors, producing a vector.

I want to use `parfor` (or `spmd`) to make things faster. However, `A` has large size so I don't want to broadcast `A` to all workers. Is there a way to do this efficiently, given that `my_func` takes sometime? If anyone can give me a small example, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cell arrays are all [sliced variables](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html). This means they will not be broadcast to all workers, only those segments each worker needs.

Thus, you can safely replace the `for` with `parfor`:

```
parfor i = 1:100
    D{i} = my_func(A{i}, B{i}, C{i});
end
```

Comment: Then its truly strange because using parfor like that is way slower than serial code. I don't know to check but if i run on 3 cores, my computer is completely frozen. So I suspect that the data was being broadcast to workers. Thanks.

Comment: @Bluesking What version of MATLAB are you on? If ≥  R2016b, then you might want to take a look at [ticBytes](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/ticbytes.html)

Comment: I was able to check the amount of data sent to each worker, about 300MB, which is about half of the size of matrix A. So it seems nothing is wrong. How come there was no advantage in running time?

Comment: I know that the startup time for a parallel pool is substantial; are you opening and closing the pool each time you run the code?

Comment: No. I opened the pool. start counting time and run the code. standard stuff. I test on other computer with 4 cores. The best it does is matching the time of serial code. Maybe this job is not hard enough. Thanks Rody.